# Round input field to 2 decimal places using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, rounding

I've made a little Inches to CM's converter using the code below

```
$(function () {
    var $src = $('#inches'),
        $dst = $('#cms');
    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val($src.val() * 2.54);
    });
});
```

The value of the `#cms` changes on keypress in the Inches box, but it can leave a lot of decimals, is there a way to stop it showing more than 2 decimal places or rounding to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toFixed` method to **always** show 2 decimal places. Note that it will **round** off the result. I am using `parseFloat` here just to be safe, but it not required as such, since the number being multiplied is 2.54, which is already a float. But in cases where integers are being used, you need `parseFloat` to **always** show the trailing decimals.

```
 $(function () {
    var $src = $('#inches'),
        $dst = $('#cms');
    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val(parseFloat($src.val() * 2.54).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the .toFixed but implemented it wrong, I'll accept the answer when it will let me

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your script:

```
function to2dp(foo) {
    var bar = (Math.round(foo * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    return bar;
}
```

...then add an onKeyUp event to call it with the new value, e.g.:

```
$('#inches').keyup(function(e) {
    var foo=$(this).val();
    if(!IsNaN(foo)) {
        $('#cms').val(to2dp(parseFloat(foo) * 2.54));
    }
}
```

Disclaimer - I haven't tried this yet - just off the top of my head :$